# Storing a custom object which contains a list<> in a database

Tags: c#, android, list, object, xamarin

I want to save a class/ object to a local SQLite database in Android. But this object contains a list. As far as I know, it is not possible to save a list to the database so I want to ignore it and populate it after the object has been loaded from the database.

I have been looking at multiple tutorials on Android databases but none of them cover how to deal with properties that can not be stored in a database.

I also looked at the xamarin documentation and tried using [ignore] without success.

[xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm)

This is the class I want to save to the database with the [ignore] still in place:

```
[Table("Room")]
public class Room
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    public string NFC_UId { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public List<Switch> RoomSwitches = new List<Switch>();

    public Room()
    {

    }
}
```

The error I get when I try to use the ignore is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0592  Attribute 'Ignore' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.

So is it possible to have the list ignored or is there any other solution to my problem?

Comment: I've not worked with android myself, but have you looked into serializing your Room object as a Json string. You can then store the whole object and restore its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i had to use [ignore] like this:

```
[Table("Room")]
public class Room
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string RoomName { get; set; }

    public string NFC_UId { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public List<Switch> RoomSwitches { get; set; } //note the get and set instead of new list

    public Room()
    {

    }

    public getswitches(){} <---
}
```

I am now using a function inside the room class(marked with <---) to get the switches after the room has been loaded from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Room from `android architectures` then you can add `TypeConverters` to your database similar to what @Wheels73 has suggested with help of `GSON`. For example you can write your type converter as:

```
class ListTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter fun fromStringToList(stringValue: String?) : List<String>? {
        val listType = object: TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.type
        return if(stringValue?.isNotEmpty == true) {
            Gson().fromJson(stringValue, listType)
        } else null
    }

    @TypeConverter fun fromListToString(listValue: List<String>?) : String? =
        Gson().toJson(listValue ?: return null)

}
```

and add this TypeConverter to your database definition:

```
@TypeConverters(ListTypeConverter::class) // add additional using ,
class MyAppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    // retrieve your DAOs
}
```

If you are not using `ROOM`. The idea is similar, use `GSON` and convert the object to or from `String` in order to create and save the list as a field. I think it would work similar in C# as well. I'm not too familiar but maybe you could use

`var listString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfObjectType)` and

`var listOfObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjectType>>(listString)`

Comment: the room is a custom object I made unfortunately

Comment: But you can try serializing the object to JSON string. For ex: changing the field to `public string RoomSwitches` you can have a methods that are `public void setRoomSwitches(List<Switch>)` and `public List<Switch> getRoomSwitches()`

Comment: i discovered how to correctly use [ignore] and found another way to solve my problem. but thx for the help